# Hibernate Criteria how to add new construction in Projections or other?

Tags: java, hibernate

With HQL I can enter the following statement can be made :

SELECT new MyClass(u.name,u.email) FROM User u ;

where MyClass is a normal Javabean with name and email as a Constructor.

I like to use Hibernate Criteria to construct such queries. Is this possible. I know I can restrict the columns to name and email using Projections but how do I get to use the new operator in Criteria ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyClass.class));
```

This is very good example [Hibernate Criteria Transformers.aliasToBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574542/hibernate-criteria-transformers-aliastobean-is-not-populating-correct-values)

Answer (score 1):

Every time I look at Criteria API code I remember why I avoid using it:
Anyway see 9.1.4 here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-typedquery-multiselect

Comment: Yes this solution works. Thanks.  Kind of like the criteria builder but I suppose its just personal taste.

Comment: Previously accepted answer looks a bit easier to work with however as you do not need a large constructor. For stongly typed queries I have been using QueryDsl recently which I find much simpler.